# .Net 5 SDK and .Net 6 SDK Side by Side Support

Tags: c#, .net-5, .net-6.0

I have a build server that I use to build my .Net 5 applications (with the .Net 5 SDK installed on it).

I would like to install the .Net 6 SDK on that same build server and use it for building both existing .Net 5 applications and for new .Net 6 applications.

But I am concerned that when I install the .Net 6 SDK, it may cause changes to the build process for .Net 5 applications.  Especially when the .Net 5 application is deployed to a server that does not have .Net 6 installed.

The reason I ask this is because historically it has been a problem.
When building two applications on the same machine, one on .Net Framework 4.0 and one on .Net Framework 4.8, there are some subtleties involved.  When you install .Net Framework 4.8, it upgrades the .Net Framework 4.0 assemblies.  Then when you build a 4.0 application, it uses 4.8 but "targets" 4.0 to try to make it look like .Net Framework 4.0 (for the .Net Framework 4.0 application).  But it is really .Net Framework 4.8.  This caused subtle, hard to find bugs.

I am wondering if there are similar issues when building a .Net 5 and .Net 6 application on the same machine.

**When I install the .Net 6 SDK on my build server, does it affect/upgrade the .Net 5 SDK libraries?**  (Similar to how .Net Framework 4.x did.)

Comment: If you're concerned about it, the proper thing to do would be to test it and verify that there are indeed no issues.

Comment: .NET Core supports side-by-side installations on runtimes and SDKs, as stated on the official documentation.

Comment: Framework-dependent deployments eliminate this concern by bundling the runtime with the deployed application. It can't pick up a newer version of the runtime by accident.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - I have not been able to find those docs.  (My searches keep bring up ".Net Framework 4.x" stuff).  Do you have a link?

Comment: @mason - I suppose I can setup a test bed and do several days of testing to verify it.  But I thought I might see if someone has already done that first (by asking this question).

Comment: @madreflection - That works for application deployments (ie Runtime).  But I am talking about building (ie the SDK).

Comment: @Vaccano: In that case, I'll refer you back to Camilo Terevinto's comment. Whichever version you have in the project file's `TargetFramework` element, *that's* the SDK version it'll use. Not something newer. Visual Studio once uninstalled .NET Core 2.something SDK (2.0, IIRC) on me during an upgrade--because it's no longer supported--without me realizing it and it broke my ability to build a project that targeted it, and I had the latest few SDK versions installed. So it doesn't use newer versions when you don't have that exact version installed.

Comment: See the official docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection) on how to select the SDK version to use, what build-time APIs to use and what runtime to target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

**Yes**

Long answer:

1. NET SDK 6 can result in a wrong PATH configuration on Windows. I have personally experienced this issue on our build server. After heavy rebooting, clearing caches on the server, we have decided to recreate it with fresh SDK installation. We had an error:

`Could not execute because the application was not found or a compatible .NET SDK is not installed.`

100% sure that the only thing that happened before was the new SDK installation.

Answer (score 3):

1. **Specify the target framework in the project file**

   After installing the different SDKs, you can specify the target framework like this. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-a-target-framework) is more information on this.

> ```xml
> <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">     
>   <PropertyGroup>
>     <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
>   </PropertyGroup>     
> </Project>
> ```

You can also instruct msbuild to [preprocess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/overview#preprocess-the-project-file) the file so you can see what it's output would look like; by running a command like this `dotnet msbuild -property:TargetFramework=netcoreapp3.1-preprocess:output.xml`.

2. **Use a global.json file**

   Create a file named [`global.json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version) in the root of your project. Specify the version in this manner

> ```
> {
>   "sdk": {
>     "version": "5.0.0"
>   }
> }
> ```

All your installations are side-by-side by default. However, when you run commands like `dotnet new` the SDK defaults to the latest version. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection) is more information on the selection process