# Is it ok to uninstall old versions of Microsoft .Net SDK?

Tags: .net, sdk

I have several old .NET SDK versions which take up a lot of disk space. Is it ok to remove the older .NET SDK versions? I seldom do .Net development myself.

My concern is that it will affect the smooth running of applications. Will it?

[image]

Comment: upgrade all soultions to the latest one, and remove others.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70312741/90475

Comment: And especially this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some features of development from Visual Studio that are tighly coupled with specific versions of .NET 4.x and .NET Core 3.1 even if you are using only the latest 4.8 and .NET 7 versions to develop. A safer course to take  is uninstall by Visual Studio Installer, select "Modify", in the "Individual Components" tab left marked only the verions of SDK are you really using.

[image]

If some Visual Studio template/feature that depends that option be removed it'll alert you.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question.

I have removed the older .Net SDKs. Everything works normally.

I am not sure whether there will be any side effects in future. So far so good.

Comment: There are some features of development from Visual Studio that are tighly coupled with specific versions of .NET 4.x and .NET Core 3.1 even if you are using only the latest 4.8 and .NET 7 versions to develop